# curlftpfs mount disagrees with the fstab

Tags: 12.04, umount

I am working with curlftpfs to mount a remote FTP directory locally in Kubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

I have the following entry in my /etc/fstab:

```
curlftpfs#ftp_user:ftp_password@ftp_server /mnt/nimh fuse ro,noexec,nosuid,nodev,noauto,user,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

I have created the directory in /mnt with the following:

```
|-> ll /mnt
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 jim fuse 4.0K Jan  6 09:56 nimh/
```

My user does belong to the fuse group as well:

```
uid=1000(jim) gid=1000(jim) groups=1000(jim),27(sudo),105(fuse)
```

I am able to mount manually without issue but then the /mnt changes to:

```
|-> mount /mnt/nimh
|-> ll /mnt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1.0K Dec 31  1969 nimh/
```

However when I attempt to umount /mnt/nimh I receive:

```
umount: /mnt/nimh mount disagrees with the fstab
```

My /etc/mtab looks like:

```
curlftpfs#ftp://ftp_user:ftp_password@ftp_server/ /mnt/nimh fuse ro,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=jim 0 0
```

I am able to umount the filesystem without issue if I sudo. Any idea what I'm missing in order to be able to unmount without having to use sudo?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Try `fusermount` to unmount the filesystem:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/nimh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution follwing using this workaround for shhfs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/99437/comments/33

Just add another fsname=XXX paramter to the options in /etc/fstab, where XXX is the first word of the line, e.g:

```
curlftpfs#ftp://ftp_user:ftp_password@ftp_server/ /mnt/nimh fuse ro,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=jim,fsname=curlftpfs#ftp://ftp_user:ftp_password@ftp_server/ 0 0
```

That did the trick for me and I can mount and unmount the ftp via nemo/nautilus as a user.